# For data validation, where to add Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")?

Tags: validation, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` app the [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation) is not working. I've noticed that some of the default `views` (such as `login.cshtml`, `Register.cshtml` that were created by `VS2017` when the app was created) have the following code at the end. But these default views are in fact partial views. My Views are not partial views, should the following be added to end of  my `views` as well? Or what should I be adding to the end of my views that are not partial views:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Comment: When you say that "is not working" what do you mean? It can be "not working" on client (javascript), "not working" on server (can be many things). What exactly is happening (define "not working")?

Comment: @dime2lo It's not working on client-side. The details are on my this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46008588/1232087).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well,

```
@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

is used for "client side validation" (javascript). It does not let the user send the form if it is not valid (according to Model Validation).

If you open your /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml you´ll see at the bottom of it the following code:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

This code block is where the content from `@section Scripts` will be injected, in these case, the content of the Partial View `_ValidationScriptsPartial`.

As `required: false`, if your view does not need client validation you does not need to add the `@section Scripts` code.

Regarding the `Partial` in `_ValidationScriptsPartial` view name it means that the view itself is partial, it is not intended to be served directly. It must not be confused with "it should be used in partial views".

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout#sections

[Injecting content into specific sections from a partial view ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor View Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with)

Regards.

Comment: You've answered my question except that I was also confused about whether `@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}` can be added to any view that needs client-side validation since the word `partial` in the code above was making me think the above code is meant for partial views only. But I think I did not put it correctly in the post. For the benefit of other readers you may want to add a one liner in your `Reply` in regard to my confusion. And I'll mark that as an `Answer`.

Comment: Have edited the answer, so others don´t get confused about the "Partial" in view´s name. (Added: Regarding the Partial in _ValidationScriptsPartial view name it means that the view itself is partial, it is not intended to be served directly. It must not be confused with "it should be used in partial views").

Comment: This is a great answer. It was spot on with what I needed. Thank you @dime2lo.