# How to make this ASP.NET Core Model Validation work on client-side?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-validation

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` app the following [Model Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation) is not working. I think the issue is related to me not properly adding validation scripts in Main View below.

**Scenario**:

1. I click on a button on Main View that calls a `partial view`.
2. I enter all correct values, in partial view and submit the form (in partial view), the form `successfully` gets submitted and all the values are correctly entered into SQL server db.
3. I then `intentionally` enter a string, say, abc into the input box for `price` (that is of `nullable type float`) and submit the form. A client side error does NOT show up even (the javascript is enabled on my Chrome browser). Hence, Form gets submitted to the server where `ModeState.IsValid`, as expected, is `false` in the POST action method.

**Question**: Why client-side validation (as shown in step 3) above is not working and how we can make it work?

**Note**: All the css and javascripts were added and configured by default by VS2017 when the project was created. So I think scripts are all there and I may not be calling them correctly on the views - but that's just an assumption.

**MyViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int FY { get; set; } 
    public byte OrderType { get; set; }
    public float? Price { get; set; } 
    ....
}
```

**Main View**

```
@model MyProj.Models.MainViewModel

...
<div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit"...>GO</button>
</div
@section scripts
{
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
     ....
     $('.tab-content').on('click', '.BtnGO', function (event) {
    ....    
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SU_AddCustOrder", "MyContr")',
        data: { ....},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (BtnVal == 'AddOrderBtnGo')
                $('#menuAP').html(data);
            else if ....
        error: function (....){
              alert(...);
        }
    });
});
```

**MyContrController**:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddCustOrder(int Order_id)
{
 ....
 return PartialView("~/Views/PartialsV/MyPartialView.cshtml", myVM);
 ....
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddCustOrder(MyViewModel model)
{
 ....
 if(ModelState.IsValid)
 {
   ....
 }
 ....
}
```

**Partial View**

```
....
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Price"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control"></input>
        <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
....
<button type="submit" name="submit"...>Add Order</button>
```

**UPDATE**

**_layout.cshtm** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Test</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    @RenderSection("styles", required:false)
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top text-center">
        </div>
        <div class="container nav nav-pills" style="margin-top:4px;background-color:cornsilk;">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("Welcome")
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer class="text-center">
            <a asp-controller="Misc" asp-action="AccessibilityStatement" class="text-center text-muted">Accessibility Statement</a>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("css", required:false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using something like `@section scripts { }` inside the partial view?

Comment: @Ali Thank you for trying to help. No, I am not using `@section scripts { }`.

Comment: Could you update the post to show where you are putting the scripts for client validation?

Comment: @Ali I've not placed the script anywhere. All I've is what `VS2017` places and configure in `_layout.cshtml` file (shown above) when one creates a web app using a default `ASP.NET Core Web Application` template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see. If you go and open Shared folder inside Views folder you will find a file called `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` that contains the validation scripts.

<s>Now the first thing to do is to add **validation attributes** such as `[Required]` to your view model.</s>

Than in **Main View** add `@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }` before `<script>`.

After you add the html of the partial view in this line `$('#menuAP').html(data);`, find the form and call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse()` like the following

```
if (BtnVal == 'AddOrderBtnGo') {
   $('#menuAP').html(data);
   var $form = $('#menuAP').find('#your-form-id-here');
   $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you for helping me). Please note that, as shown in the model above, `float?` is nullable and hence not a Required field. So I did not have to use `[Required]` DataAnnotation. But the key was your suggestion of adding `@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); } before <script>` before `<script>` and most importantly the last two lines of your `Ajax` code above. For the benefit of other readers, you may want to remove the `[Required]` part in your Reply above as that is not needed for the question asked.