# How to add an annotation to property after updating database using migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, data-annotations, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm creating an MVC ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web application, and in the middle of the project I added the following properties and annotations to the ApplicationUser class.

```
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} can't have more than 100 characters.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} can't have more than 100 characters.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
```

However, I accidentally run add-migration and update-database before adding another annotation to DateOfBirth:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

What is the way to correct the mistake? How can I add the annotation now?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  add  another annotation to DateOfBirth now. Because changing the Display data annotation for a property won’t have influence on the database schema.

There is a similar problem here:

[Do we still need to run Add-Migration if we change only Display attribute of data Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928661/do-we-still-need-to-run-add-migration-if-we-change-only-display-attribute-of-dat)

I find the related document that code first data annotations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations